# read from hebrew text file java 8

Tags: java, file, io, hebrew

I'm tring to read from text file in hebrew but i get some jebrish...

this is my code:

```
try {
        workFile =new File("tripShosWork.txt");
        homeFile =new File("tripShosHome.txt");
        BufferedReader homeBr =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(homeFile));
        BufferedReader workBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(workFile));
        home = new String [98];
        for (int i = 0; i < home.length; i++) 
            home[i] = homeBr.readLine();
        work = new String [19];
        for (int i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
            work[i] = workBr.readLine(); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(work));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(home));
```

i need your help!

Comment: what is the encoding of the file? CP862? UTF8? UTF16? UTF32?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("tripShosWork.txt");
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis, "Cp1255");
```

This assumes that the file is in the Windows Hebrew encoding. Use `"ISO8859_8"` for Latin-8.